# Getting an error in Android Studio, " Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3796" which I can not resolve

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling

I'm getting this error in Android Studio when I try and launch my app. I'm relatively new to Android and I can't make heads or tails of it.

```
    06-13 01:45:21.065 3796-3796/com.example.leo.ConnexusHealth W/art: Large object allocation failed: Failed anonymous mmap(0x0, 387129344, 0x3, 0x2, 28, 0): Out of memory. See process maps in the log.
06-13 01:45:21.065 3796-3796/? W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 387125436 byte allocation with 1036624 free bytes and 382MB until OOM"
06-13 01:45:21.071 3796-3796/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
06-13 01:45:21.071 3796-3796/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
06-13 01:45:21.081 3796-3796/? I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(592B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 44% free, 1255KB/2MB, paused 1.545ms total 9.679ms
06-13 01:45:21.081 3796-3796/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
06-13 01:45:21.090 3796-3796/? I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 44% free, 1255KB/2MB, paused 1.636ms total 8.693ms
06-13 01:45:21.091 3796-3796/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
06-13 01:45:21.146 3796-3796/? I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 44% free, 1266KB/2MB, paused 904us total 45.367ms
06-13 01:45:21.148 3796-3796/? I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 369MB allocation
06-13 01:45:21.161 3796-3796/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
06-13 01:45:21.195 3796-3796/? I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 44% free, 1255KB/2MB, paused 1.006ms total 29.842ms
06-13 01:45:21.196 3796-3796/? W/art: Disabled moving GC due to the non moving space being full
06-13 01:45:21.251 3796-3806/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 370MB/370MB, paused 5.291ms total 35.508ms
06-13 01:45:24.161 3796-3796/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 3796 (.ConnexusHealth)
```

Again this error occurs when I try to run the app. I can't really make sense of any of the other solutions on stack overflow. Below is the rest of my code:

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.leoconnelly.connexus">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/connexus_logo" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/connexus_logo_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"         android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:largeHeap="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HealthCenterListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".HealthCenterSelectedActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MoreInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RecordHealthInfo" />
        <activity android:name=".SelectCity"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCvjWU00ZJxl273Idt9h9fLbMJuG-Rfe6w"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="27.1.1" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Next are all my classes I suspect are involved:

```
enter code herepackage com.example.leoconnelly.connexus;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by celiachen on 2/5/18.
 */

public class HealthCenterButton {

    // instance variables or fields
    public String nameOfCenter;
    public String neighborhood;
    public String imageUrl;
    public Double lat;
    public Double longi;
    public String mini;

    // constructor
    // default

    // method
    // static methods that read the json file in and load into Recipe

    // static method that loads our healthCenters.json using the helper method
    // this method will return an array list of recipes constructed from the JSON
    // file
    public static ArrayList<HealthCenterButton> getHealthCentersFromFile(String filename, Context context){
        ArrayList<HealthCenterButton> healthCenterList = new ArrayList<HealthCenterButton>();

        //ArrayList<HealthCenterButton> miniList = new ArrayList<HealthCenterButton>();


        // try to read from JSON file
        // get information by using the tags
        // construct a Recipe Object for each recipe in JSON
        // add the object to arraylist
        // return arraylist
        try{
            String jsonString = loadJsonFromAsset("healthCenters.json", context);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray recipes = json.getJSONArray("recipes");

            // for loop to go through each recipe in your recipes array

            for (int i = 0; i < recipes.length(); i++){
                HealthCenterButton recipe = new HealthCenterButton();
                recipe.nameOfCenter = recipes.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
                recipe.neighborhood = recipes.getJSONObject(i).getString("url");
                recipe.imageUrl = recipes.getJSONObject(i).getString("image");
                recipe.lat = recipes.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("lat");
                recipe.longi = recipes.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("longi");
                recipe.mini = recipes.getJSONObject(i).getString("mini");
                // add to arraylist
                healthCenterList.add(recipe);

            }
           /* for (int i = 0; i < recipes.length(); i++){
                HealthCenterButton recipe = new HealthCenterButton();
                recipe.mini = recipes.getJSONObject(i).getString("mini");
                // add to arraylist
                miniList.add(recipe);

            }
*/

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return healthCenterList;


    }


    // helper method that loads from any Json file
    private static String loadJsonFromAsset(String filename, Context context) {
        String json = null;

        try {
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(filename);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return json;
    }



}
```

Here's my next class:

```
   package com.example.leoconnelly.connexus;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Created by celiachen on 2/7/18.
     */

    // adapter is needed when you want to do any sort of list or table view
    // gets data and decides where to display in the activity

    public class HealthCenterButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        // adapter takes the app itself and a list of data to display
        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<HealthCenterButton> mHealthCentersList;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        public Typeface custom_fontA;
        public Typeface custom_fontB;
        public Typeface custom_fontC;
        public Typeface custom_fontD;




        // constructor
        public HealthCenterButtonAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<HealthCenterButton> mHealthCentersList){

            //line of SO
            //super(mContext);

            mContext.getAssets();

            // initialize instances variables
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mHealthCentersList = mHealthCentersList;
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

             custom_fontA = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),  "fonts/NeuzeitGro.ttf");
             custom_fontB = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),  "fonts/NeuzeitSLTBookHeavy.ttf");
             custom_fontC = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),  "fonts/DINNeuzeitGroteskStd-BdCond.otf");
             //custom_fontD = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),  "fonts/DINNeuzeitGroteskStd-Light.otf");

        }


        // methods
        // a list of methods we need to override

        // gives you the number of recipes in the data source
        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return mHealthCentersList.size();
        }

        // returns the item at specific position in the data source

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position){
            return mHealthCentersList.get(position);
        }

        // returns the row id associated with the specific position in the list
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position){
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            ViewHolder holder;

            // check if the view already exists
            // if yes, you don't need to inflate and findViewbyID again
            if (convertView == null){
                // inflate
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.find_care_health_centers_list, parent, false);
                // add the views to the holder
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                // views
                holder.nameOfCenterTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.health_center_list_title);
                holder.neighborhoodTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.neighborhood);
                holder.thumbnailImageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.health_center_list_image);
                // add the holder to the view
                // for future use
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else{
                // get the view holder from converview
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            //set custom fonts



            //end

            // get relavate subview of the row view
            TextView nameOfCenterTextView = holder.nameOfCenterTextView;
            TextView neighborhoodTextView = holder.neighborhoodTextView;
            ImageView thumbnailImageView = holder.thumbnailImageView;

            // get corresonpinding recipe for each row
            HealthCenterButton healthCenterButton = (HealthCenterButton)getItem(position);


            // update the row view's textviews and imageview to display the information

            // titleTextView
            nameOfCenterTextView.setText(healthCenterButton.nameOfCenter);
            nameOfCenterTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorAccent));
            nameOfCenterTextView.setTextSize(18);
            nameOfCenterTextView.setTypeface(custom_fontB);

            // servingTextView
            neighborhoodTextView.setText(healthCenterButton.neighborhood);
            neighborhoodTextView.setTextSize(14);
            neighborhoodTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            neighborhoodTextView.setTypeface(custom_fontA);


            // imageView
            // use Picasso library to load image from the image url
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(healthCenterButton.imageUrl).into(thumbnailImageView);




            return convertView;
        }

        // viewHolder
        // is used to customize what you want to put into the view
        // it depends on the layout design of your row
        // this will be a private static class you have to define
        private static class ViewHolder{
            public TextView nameOfCenterTextView;
            public TextView neighborhoodTextView;
            public ImageView thumbnailImageView;
        }



        // intent is used to pass information between activities
        // intent -> pacakge
        // sender, receiver

    }


    package com.example.leoconnelly.connexus;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by leoconnelly on 4/9/18.
 */

public class HealthCenterListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mListView ;
    public Context mContext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hospitals_list_view);

        final ArrayList<HealthCenterButton> healthCentersList = HealthCenterButton.getHealthCentersFromFile("healthCenters.json", this);

        if (healthCentersList.size()==2) {
            System.out.println("YES YES YES YES");
        }


        mContext = this;


    //    String x = healthCentersList.get(2).toString();
      //  System.out.println(x);

        HealthCenterButtonAdapter adapter = new HealthCenterButtonAdapter(this, healthCentersList);


        //set the views
        mListView = findViewById(R.id.hospitals_list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);


        //set up the positions for the next screen
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id){


              HealthCenterButton SelectedHealthCareCenter = healthCentersList.get(position);

                Intent detailIntent = new Intent(mContext, HealthCenterSelectedActivity.class);

                detailIntent.putExtra("latitude", SelectedHealthCareCenter.lat);
                detailIntent.putExtra("longitude", SelectedHealthCareCenter.longi);
                detailIntent.putExtra("nameOfCenter", SelectedHealthCareCenter.nameOfCenter);
                detailIntent.putExtra("neighborhood", SelectedHealthCareCenter.neighborhood);
                detailIntent.putExtra("imageUrl", SelectedHealthCareCenter.imageUrl);
                detailIntent.putExtra("miniUrl", SelectedHealthCareCenter.imageUrl);


                startActivity(detailIntent);

            }

        });



       //get arraylists



            //get adapter






        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the log itself, the error is generated because of "out of memory exception". While using location request and google maps you might need to take care a little bit of your code optimization and allocation of Objects that used for getting a location and Objects for use of maps. And also take care of permission. This shall remove this error.

I cannot say more about your question due to lack of usage of these objects I've mentioned.